# mysql - apply result of stored procedure (using dynamic sql) in an update query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to run a stored procedure for every row in a table and update the row with the result.

I picture something like this:

```
UPDATE `vouchers` SET `code` = (CALL voucherCode('db.vouchers', 3, 4))
WHERE `code` IS NULL;
```

Using a Function is not an option, as the stored procedure contains dynamic sql. It's also okay to use an output parameter if that is easier than using the result set. Currently the procedure is defined as below, but can easily be adopted to yield a single row result to behave as intended in the above code sample.

```
`voucherCode`( IN `tableName` VARCHAR(40),
IN `segments` INT(32), IN `segmentLength` INT(32), OUT `code` VARCHAR(32) )
```

The only solution I came up so far is to create another stored procedure which utilizes a cursor to iterate through the vouchers table, and call the `voucherCode`-procedure within the loop.

*So what is the best way to call a stored procedure from within an insert or an update query?*

Comment: seems like a strange way to try to use a stored procedure - why not do the update in the sp itself?

Comment: @RyanVincent That's certainly also the only solution I found so far. However I'm still hopung somebody out there knows an easier way which allows me to use the stored procedure from within a query.

Comment: @RamRaider because I also use the stored procedure in other contexts like inserts or I use it from within another stored procedure, to me this is a versatile construct that's reused all over my dbs.